# Eclipse Git Preferences: Cannot change which user space .gitconfig to use

Tags: git, eclipse, git-config

As you can see in the picture, eclipse is searching the user space `.gitconfig` in the specified location. I have my `.gitconfig` in another location though. Unfortunately the Location textbox is not editable and the Open button will not let me choose a file either.

How can I force Eclipse to use my specific file in the specific location?

[image]

Comment: Click on `Open` and select the file?

Comment: The ```Open``` button does not open a file selector, it only opens the selected file in Eclipse

Comment: The location is given by Git and you have to set or change the `HOME` environment variable for that (which also affects the default location to store repositories).

Comment: Create a symlink?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed a problem like this in our enterprise.  We don't have "HOME" set in Windows, and because of that eGit makes a bad guess about where "HOME" should be.

My workaround was to write the following very short batch file, called "runwithhome.cmd":

```
set HOME=C:\Users\%USERNAME%
start /min %*
```

We do have "USERNAME" properly set in our environment, so that works.  I then changed the Eclipse shortcut so that the absolute path to this batch file, followed by a space, was put at the beginning of the "Target" command line.

Your situation is different, but it should be obvious how to customize this to your situation.